# i am not able to implement to resize div by mouse using JQuery on IE9

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

JQuery Browser compatibility issue:
I am not able to  implement to resize div by mouse using JQuery on IE9 ,can anyone help.it works on rest of the browsers. i have checked for Chrome,FF,IE8. I am using Jquery 1.7 version.

```
<script> 
    $(function() {$( "#AccountTree" ).resizable(); }); 
</script> 
<div class="scrolling grey_panel_border" 
        style="width:100%;height:90%;float:left;" 
        align="center" id="AccountTree"> 
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="Accounttree" />     
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code...what have you tried?

Comment: <script>
 $(function() {
  $( "#AccountTree" ).resizable();
 });
</script>




<div class="scrolling grey_panel_border" style="width:100%;height:90%;float:left;" align="center" id="AccountTree">
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="Accounttree" />      
</div>

Comment: Above is my code. It works on all browsers except IE9

Comment: Usually it is better to edit your post than to add the code in the comments so that new reader will see your code without reading comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KEQyf/8/

I am using IE9 Version 9.0.8112.16421 and it works fine.